# Use java script in asp.net mvc 4 to copy mailing address into physical address

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html.checkbox

I am creating a registration page for a project. The users can have two types of addresses: mailing and physical. There are instances when these addresses will be the same. I am trying to create a checkbox that calls a java script to copy the mailing address fields into the physical address fields. I used [this reference](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?61444-Using-the-check-box-to-auto-fill-in-text-fields) to create the html code below. The code is not working and I cannot determine why. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!--Mailing Address-->
<div class="form-group">
    <br/><h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address)</h3>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
    <!--Mailing location name-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.name, new { @name = "M_name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing street address-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.street_address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.street_address, new { @name = "M_street_address", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing Suite-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.suite_number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.suite_number, new { @name = "M_suite_number", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing City-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.city, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.city, new { @name = "M_city", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing State-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.state, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.state, new { @name = "M_state", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing Zip-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.zip_code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.zip_code, new { @name = "M_zip", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>


<!--Script to copy mailing address into physical address-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyMailing(f)
        f.elements['P_name'].value = document.getElementById['M_name'].value;
        f.elements['P_street_address'].value = document.getElementById['M_street_address'].value;
        f.elements['P_suite_number'].value = document.getElementById['M_suite_number'].value;
        f.elements['P_city'].value = document.getElementById['M_city'].value;
        f.elements['P_state'].value = document.getElementById['M_state'].value;
        f.elements['P_zip'].value = document.getElementById['M_zip'].value;
    }
</script>


<!--Physical Address-->
<div class="form-group">
    <br/><h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address)</h3>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Same as Mailing @Html.CheckBox("Same as Mailing Address", new { @onclick = "if (this.checked) copyMailing(this.form)", @class = "checkbox" }) <!--String passed in is used for both value and id of checkbox-->
    </label>   
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical location name-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.name, new { @name = "P_name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical street address-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.street_address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.street_address, new { @name = "P_street_address", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical Suite-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.suite_number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.suite_number, new { @name = "P_suite_number", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical City-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.city, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.city, new { @name = "P_city", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical State-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.state, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.state, new { @name = "P_state", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical Zip-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.zip_code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.zip_code, new { @name = "P_zip", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I should mention that I also tried this version of the script:

```
<!--Script to copy mailing address into physical address-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyMailing() {
        document.getElementById("P_name").innerHTML = document.getElementById("M_name").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("P_street_address").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("M_street_address").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("P_suite_number").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("M_suite_number").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("P_city").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("M_city").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("P_state").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("M_state").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("P_zip").innerHTML = document.getElementById("M_zip").innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

Response to first answer: Thanks for the suggested fix. Here is my edited code. Unfortunately, it still does not work. Any other suggestions?

```
<!--Mailing Address-->
<div class="form-group">
    <br/><h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address)</h3>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
    <!--Mailing location name-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.name, new { @id = "M_name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing street address-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.street_address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.street_address, new { @id = "M_street_address", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing Suite-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.suite_number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.suite_number, new { @id = "M_suite_number", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing City-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.city, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.city, new { @id = "M_city", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing State-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.state, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.state, new { @id = "M_state", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing Zip-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.zip_code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.zip_code, new { @id = "M_zip", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>


<!--Physical Address-->
<div class="form-group">
    <br/><h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address)</h3>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Same as Mailing @Html.CheckBox("Same as Mailing Address", new { @onclick = "if (this.checked) copyMailing(this.form)", @class = "checkbox" }) <!--String passed in is used for both value and id of checkbox-->
    </label>   
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical location name-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.name, new { @id = "P_name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical street address-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.street_address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.street_address, new { @id = "P_street_address", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical Suite-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.suite_number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.suite_number, new { @id = "P_suite_number", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical City-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.city, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.city, new { @id = "P_city", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical State-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.state, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.state, new { @id = "P_state", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical Zip-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.zip_code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.zip_code, new { @id = "P_zip", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>


<!--Script to copy mailing address into physical address-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyMailing(f) {
    f.elements['P_name'].value = document.getElementById['M_name'].value;
    f.elements['P_street_address'].value = document.getElementById['M_street_address'].value;
    f.elements['P_suite_number'].value = document.getElementById['M_suite_number'].value;
    f.elements['P_city'].value = document.getElementById['M_city'].value;
    f.elements['P_state'].value = document.getElementById['M_state'].value;
    f.elements['P_zip'].value = document.getElementById['M_zip'].value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: try debugging the code with `FireBug` or any other plugin of the sort, place a `debugger;` in your javascript code and move step-by-step to see where the problem lies...

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help! The code is now working. I've made a new "answer" to include the working code, below:

```
<!--Mailing Address-->
<div class="form-group">
    <br/><h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address)</h3>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
    <!--Mailing location name-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.name, new { @id = "M_name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing street address-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.street_address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.street_address, new { @id = "M_street_address", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing Suite-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.suite_number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.suite_number, new { @id = "M_suite_number", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing City-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.city, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.city, new { @id = "M_city", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing State-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.state, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.state, new { @id = "M_state", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Mailing Zip-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.zip_code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mailing_Address.zip_code, new { @id = "M_zip", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>


<!--Physical Address-->
<div class="form-group">
    <br/><h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address)</h3>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Same as Mailing @Html.CheckBox("Same as Mailing Address", new { @onclick = "if (this.checked) copyMailing(this.form)", @class = "checkbox" }) <!--String passed in is used for both value and id of checkbox-->
    </label>   
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical location name-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.name, new { @id = "P_name", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical street address-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.street_address, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.street_address, new { @id = "P_street_address", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical Suite-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.suite_number, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.suite_number, new { @id = "P_suite_number", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical City-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.city, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.city, new { @id = "P_city", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical State-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.state, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.state, new { @id = "P_state", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <!--Physical Zip-->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Physical_Address.zip_code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Physical_Address.zip_code, new { @id = "P_zip", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>


<!--Script to copy mailing address into physical address-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyMailing(f)
{
    f.elements['P_name'].value = f.elements['M_name'].value;
    f.elements['P_street_address'].value = f.elements['M_street_address'].value;
    f.elements['P_suite_number'].value = f.elements['M_suite_number'].value;
    f.elements['P_city'].value = f.elements['M_city'].value;
    f.elements['P_state'].value = f.elements['M_state'].value;
    f.elements['P_zip'].value = f.elements['M_zip'].value;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow. I give you a correct answer pointing out all your mistakes but instead of acknowledging and accepting it you post this. Best of luck getting help in the future.